# Wait for server data in order to initialize service

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I want to create an angular service that when the app is loaded for the first time will fetch data from the server **once** and then I'll be able to query the data from the local service object. Here's how I tried to do it:

```
angular.module('my.services').factory('Properties', function ($http) {

  var properties = $http.get("/properties");

  return {
    get: function (property) {
      // Logic here
      console.log(property);
    }
  }
});
```

Problem is - `$http.get()` is asynchronous and in order to achieve what I'm trying to do, I have to use it synchronously. Is there a way to do it with "native" AngularJS? Or I must use an XHR call for this?

Comment: you can use ui-router's resolve to get all async data as variables into your controller https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Comment: @webduvet - Thanks, but I don't think that's what I'm looking for. I'm trying to load a map of properties from the server. Something that is relevant to all of the application, always, and should be loaded once. I'd rather avoid ui-router in this case as it has nothing to do with a specific state. Unless, of course, I'm missing something.

Comment: service always initialize once, you can postpone initialisation of the app controller until your promise in service is resolved. Or you can always work with promise as in @Dmitriy Nevzorov's answer. It's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do something like this

```
angular.module('my.services').factory('Properties', function ($http) {

  var propertiesPromise = $http.get("/properties");

  return {
    get: function (property) {
      propertiesPromise.then(function(properties){
        console.log(properties);
      });
    }
  }
});
```