# Using data from server in a service

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I already [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36696939/2083523) about the topic so this is in fact a followup:

I want to create an angular service that when the app is loaded for the first time will fetch data from the server **once** and then I'll be able to query the data from the local service object. Here's how I tried to do it:

```
angular.module('my.services').factory('Properties', function ($http) {

  var properties = $http.get("/properties");

  return {
    get: function (property) {          
      return properties[property];
    }
  }
});
```

Problem is - `$http.get()` is asynchronous and in order to achieve what I'm trying to do, I have to use it synchronously. Is there a way to do it with "native" AngularJS? Or I must use an XHR call for this?

**Just for clarification**: The difference between this question and original one is that I do not only want to do something with `property` like printing it to the log. I in fact want to use `property` as a key to the data returned from the server. If the data is not yet there when a controller calls `get` - I would like for it to wait until the data is returned.

Here's what I have now which is very not elegant:

```
return {
    get: function (property) {
      while(!properties.$resolved) {
        setTimeout(function() {}, 2000)
      }
      return properties[property];
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
return properties[property];
```

won't work. Remember that `properties` is a promise. It probably doesn't contain a property called `property`. You have to use it like this:

```
  return {
    get: function (property) {          
      return properties.then(function(response){
        return response.data[property];
      })
    }
  }
```

This will return a promise with 'property' as inner result. So in your controller, use it like this:

```
Properties.get(myProp).then(function(property){
    //do something
});
```

Secondly, to wait for a promise to resolve before the controller gets called (I'm not sure if you really need this):use the `resolve` property of the `angular ui router` library. More info here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Comment: Isn't there a way to wait for the properties object to be resolved and return the property without using `then` in the controller? It makes the code more complex for no reason. I'm trying to have a service that loads properties from the server and then provide them to the entire app. If I have to call `then` each time it's going to complicate the readability of the code for no real reason.

Comment: You could cache the property itself instead of the promise. So instead of var properties = $http... you set properties after the http call returns, and you store the actual data in properties. Then, you can expose a function to just return the property, and you wouldn't have to use 'then' in the controller. But, the downside is that before using the controller, you MUST be sure that the promise is resolved, otherwise the function won't return anything. So you have to add the resolve parameter on each controller that uses the service. I think using 'then' in the controller is more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

Inject $q in your service, then:

```
 return {

   get: function(property){

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get("/properties").then(function(res){

     deferred.resolve(res.data[property]);

     }).catch(function(err){

       //handle error
       console.log(err);
       deferred.reject(err)

      })

      return deferred.promise;

    }

 }
```

Then call it in your controller like this:

```
Properties.get(prop).then(function(res){

  $scope.mydata = res; //or whatever;

}).catch(function(err){

   alert(JSON.stringify(err));

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('my.services').factory('Properties', function ($http) {
  var properties = $http.get("/properties");

  return {
    get: function (property) {   
      properties.then(function(data) {
        return data[property];
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Haven't tested it, but I imagine 'property' is a key in the returning data.

Comment: In this case nothing will be returned from the `get` I think. Am I wrong?